# C++ server side not blocking on listen()

Tags: c++, sockets, connection, server, winsock

The code below doesn't block on listen(), it just finishes execution. Could you tell me why? (initWSA returns true, I checked it). I'm following a tutorial and I was told it should block because it's looking for clients to connect.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;

#define PORT 10000
bool initWSA(){
    WSADATA wsadata;
    int error = WSAStartup(0x0202, &wsadata);
    if (error) return false;
    if (wsadata.wVersion != 0x0202){
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
void closeConnection(SOCKET s)
{
    //Close the socket if it exists
    if (s)
        closesocket(s);

    WSACleanup(); //Clean up Winsock
}
int main(){
    initWSA();
    SOCKET s;
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) cout << "INVALID SOCKET" << endl;
    if (bind(s, (LPSOCKADDR)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
    cout << "SOCKET ERROR" << endl;
    }
    listen(s, SOMAXCONN);
    //cout << "CAUGHT ONE" << endl;
    //closeConnection(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: listen() is non-blocking.  accept() blocks and returns a client<>server socket upon connection.

Comment: what does listen do then ?

Comment: Err.. man listen, or Google 'listen()'

Comment: So should I call listen and then accept after it ?
EDIT: Yep it worked, thanks, you can post the answer :)

Comment: `listen()` tells the OS to start queuing would-be clients that `connect()` to your server (and a hint at how many pending connections to allow)... `accept()` actually makes the peer-to-peer connections.  You should indeed `accept()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, let's clarify the exact semantics of the `listen()` and `accept()` functions.

## [listen function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739168%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The listen function places a socket in a state in which it is listening for an incoming connection.
>
> ### Remarks:
>
> To accept connections, a socket is first created with the **socket** function and bound to a local address with the **bind** function. A backlog for incoming connections is specified with **listen**, and then the connections are accepted with the **accept** function. Sockets that are connection oriented, those of type **SOCK_STREAM** for example, are used with **listen**. The socket s is put into passive mode where incoming connection requests are acknowledged and queued pending acceptance by the process.

## [accept function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The accept function permits an incoming connection attempt on a socket.
>
> ### Remarks:
>
> The **accept** function extracts the first connection on the queue of pending connections on socket s. It then creates and returns a handle to the new socket. The newly created socket is the socket that will handle the actual connection; it has the same properties as socket s, including the asynchronous events registered with the **WSAAsyncSelect** or **WSAEventSelect** functions.
>
> The **accept** function can block the caller until a connection is present if no pending connections are present on the queue, and the socket is marked as blocking. If the socket is marked as nonblocking and no pending connections are present on the queue, **accept** returns an error as described in the following. After the successful completion of **accept** returns a new socket handle, the accepted socket cannot be used to accept more connections. The original socket remains open and listens for new connection requests.

## The appropriate example ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

```
...
//----------------------
// Listen for incoming connection requests.
// on the created socket
if (listen(ListenSocket, 1) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    wprintf(L"listen failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
//----------------------
// Create a SOCKET for accepting incoming requests.
SOCKET AcceptSocket;
wprintf(L"Waiting for client to connect...\n");

//----------------------
// Accept the connection.
AcceptSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
if (AcceptSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    wprintf(L"accept failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
} else
    wprintf(L"Client connected.\n");

// No longer need server socket
closesocket(ListenSocket);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer.